# Importing a zip library in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, importerror

I'm trying to use the [Fast MD5 Implementation](http://www.twmacinta.com/myjava/fast_md5.php) but I'm having trouble importing it into my project. I've tried Project Structure -> Libraries and then adding the folder, and I've also tried copying the com.twmackinta folder into my src directory. If I use one of the functions from the library, IntelliJ suggests adding the import `import com.twmacinta.util.MD5;`, but when running I get the error `java:package.com.twmacinta.util does not exist`.

What's the correct way to do this (and why should it be so hard..) ?

(Ignore the [Fast MD5 jar](http://apps.geomajas.org/nexus/content/groups/public/com/twmacinta/fast-md5/2.7.1/) file in the picture. It works, but it's a 3rd party jar and not a part of the official source, so I would still like to know how to solve the problem.)
[image]

Comment: Is the library a jar file or set of classes in a folder? What is your project structure (i.e. how are files/folders organized)? A screenshot would be very helpful.

Comment: The library is a set of classes in a folder. I have uploaded a screenshot -- the library is also in a jar-file there, and that file solved my problem, but the jar file is not a part of the official source. I'd still like to know how to do this, if anyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

If the library doesn't require a specific build process, the easiest would be to add the source files directly. You can do it by:

1. In the project tree, right click on the folder `fast-md5-2.7.1/fast-md5/src`
2. In the context menu, click `Mark Directory as -> Sources Root`

Alternatively, you may open the module settings and add designate the directory as a source directory there.